# ST_Intersection returns error in snowflake

Tags: qgis, snowflake

I have two tables containing geometry columns. Table t1 holds the multipolygon data of parcels, and table t2 contains the multipolygon data of wireless coverage areas. The multipolygons in t2 are larger in area compared to those in t1. In Snowflake, I utilized the built-in function ST_Within to identify which polygons from t1 are completely within the polygons of t2. For the remaining polygons of t1 that are not fully contained within t2, I hypothesized that some might be intersecting with them. Therefore, I decided to use the ST_Intersection function to calculate the intersecting area. However, when I executed the code, it resulted in an error.

Upon further inspection of the data in QGIS, I discovered that one of the problematic polygons from t1 is indeed completely within a polygon of t2, as depicted in the attached images.
[image]
[image]
However, the presence of a rectangle drawn along the boundary of the polygon confuses me. It appears to be part of the larger polygon from table t2. Could an expert clarify the significance of this rectangle drawn on the boundary of the polygon? Is this rectangle the reason I am experiencing issues?